# Installl a specific version of a portage overlay package

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I need to install an older version of [x11-libs/bamf](http://gpo.zugaina.org/x11-libs/bamf) package , as you can see below there are different versions available I want to install **0.5.0[2]**, but it always go to 9999 version using "emerge bamf" i even used "emerge bamf-0.5.2" but no luck, how can I tell the portage which version I need?

```
USER ~ # eix bamf
* x11-libs/bamf
     Available versions:  
     (0)    ~0.3.6-r200[1] 0.5.0[2] (**)9999[2]
     (3)    (~)0.3.6-r300[1]
       {doc +introspection static-libs}
     Homepage:            https://launchpad.net/bamf
     Description:         BAMF Application Matching Framework

[1] "angelos" /var/lib/layman/angelos
[2] "elementary" /var/lib/layman/elementary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `=` at the beginning of the package name, so try

```
emerge -a =x11-libs/bamf-0.5.0
```

You can also add a line to `/etc/portage/package.mask` in order to prevent emerge installing higher version:

```
>x11-libs/bamf-0.5.0
```

Comment: Using the `=` is dangerous, as the next time the package is upgraded, the specific version will be ignored.  As such, add the package atom to `/etc/portage/package.mask` first then emerge the package without the `=`.

Answer (score 6):

As [jimmij pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187185/6993), you can select a particular version by prefixing the package atom with an equals ('=') sign. But you can also tell emerge which overlay to use.

I we assume that there exists an ebuild for x11-libs/bamf-0.5.0 in two or more overlays, you could select an particular overlay by appending `::<overlayName>` to the end of the package atom.

For example

```
emerge -a x11-libs/bamf::elementary
```

or with the version specified

```
emerge -a =x11-libs/bamf-0.5.0::elementary
```